# set up htaccess to point 404 errors to subdomain + folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-404

I want to move my website to a subdomain, but without hurting my SEO and backlinks.

so http://www.website.com/category/page

would become http://subdomain.website.com/category/page

I was thinking of making htaccess forward to the subdomain, but with the /category/page still in the url.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file of your `www.website.com` document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect traffic to the subdomain if you have access to the control panel of the website.

For example, if you are using a cpanel, click on redirection and point the main domain(www.abc.com) to the subdomain(subdomain.abc.com)